# Slider that follows a curve

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I'm trying to make a slider that follows a curve and that I can crontrol like a normal slider.

I was googling for several days, asking to some programmer friends but no one knew how I can do that.
I would do this animation without using Flash, I was looking something in html5, jquery or javascript.

Any ideas? Is it possible to make something like this?

Thanks

Comment: [After all that work you did, how did you not find this in 10 seconds of gooling 'curved jQuery slider'](http://www.websitemaintenancelabs.com/dev-blog/curved-rounded-or-circular-sliders-javascript-jquery-ui)

Comment: and there is a so post too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186135/jquery-rounded-slider

Comment: Thanks guys, I saw the second post on stackoveflow, but the issue is the curve what I wanna do it is more similar to a wave, but I think that I can change the equation and should workd. Thanks again